# Google Drive File show unknown size in Chrome/IDm download

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api

I upload apk/mp3 file in google drive. But when I download them from browser it’s show unknown size. I mean that

"When the download starts in Chrome,IDM,etc it shows the download size as unknown. However the file size can be seen in google drive file attachment ares, but while download it doesn't shows the file size"

Answer (score 4):

Let IDM download a few moments, then press the cancel button. The file size, percentage and resume capability will appear on IDM when you continue the download.

It seems, at the beginning of the download, google drive doesn't send "content-length" attribute in the HTTP header.

**Update:**

When you right-click a file in google drive and select "download" from context menu, an AJAX request is send to the server program which create a temporary URl for download and give it to the client. unfortunately, it's missing "content-length" attribute. That's why the first attempt to download will displaying unknown file size.

If you pause and resume download, client will send a request to the temporary URL, but this time the request is not intervened by server program, rather, it's directly connect to the web server. What make difference between IDM and chrome is: IDM send "range" attribute to download in chunks, while chrome is not.

Is the sending of "range" attribute bring out a "content-length" attribute which cure the problem ? I cannot prove it. I cannot use a sniffer to peek into HTTP communication between IDM and Google Drive since it's HTTPS/TLS. So what I can do now is make a deduction.

I'm afraid, unless the missing "content-length" attribute is fixed up, chrome alone is not adequate to handle this issue.

Comment: Yes in IDM it's ok but what about Chrome.

Comment: Read my update above.